# overload action for number of parameters in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, routes, url-routing

Is it possible to overload the action methods based on number of parameters in request?

Eg:

**1.**
`domain.com/List/Filter/ByName`
invokes -> `public ActionResult Filter(string criteria1)`

**2.**
`domain.com/List/Filter/ByName/ByRanking`
invokes -> `public ActionResult Filter(string criteria1, string criteria2)`

I'm using asp.net mvc2.

Comment: Unsure but in your ActionResult method, you can programmatically call other ActionResult methods. I do a lot of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken the best way to do this would be to  add two different controller methods and map them to two different Urls.

```
public ActionResult Filter1(string criteria1);

public ActionResult Filter2(string criteria1, criteria2);
```

Then you have two route definitions:

This will map this URL  `List/Filter/xxCriteria/` to the first controller

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Filter",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/Filter/{criteria1}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "List", action = "Filter1", criteria="" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
```

This will map this URL  `List/Filter/xxCriteriaName/xxxCriteriaRank` to the second controller. Without this route you could still map a url to the second method, but it would look like : `List/Filter/?criteria1=xx&criteria2=xx`

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Filter2",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/Filter/{criteria1}/{criteria2}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "List", action = "Filter2", criteria1 = "", criteria2 = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: Whoops : Hey I didn't mean to use overloads, but two different filter methods. Edited the question! =P

Comment: I get resource not found in one of the url, but the second url works fine. What could be the problem?

Comment: @maxxxee ah, its just the url should be `{criteria1}` I forgot the **1** See my edit history. Changed it in the answer.

Comment: context.MapRoute(
                "filetr_c1",
                "Admin/{controller}/Filter/{searchby1}",
                new { controller = "List", action = "GetByCriteria2", searchby1 = "" }
            );
            
context.MapRoute(
                "filer_c2",
                "Admin/{controller}/Filter/{searchby1}/{searchby2}",
                new { controller = "List", action = "GetByCriteria2", searchby1 = "", searchby2 = "" }
            );

Comment: my route code is given above, it does not work. The first route gives "resource cannot be found" error. second works ok.

sample urls:
url with these pattern does not  work

http://localhost:52247/Admin/List/Filer/3-TestUser

Comment: @maxxxee are you sure you want the first url to point to GetByCriteria2 ?? Thats what your code is doing.. also your sample url has Filer instead of Filter ? You can also try putting List instead of {controller} if the controller will always be Lis

Answer (score 3):

Action methods cannot be overloaded based on parameters because there would be no reasonable way to disambiguate a URL into multiple overloaded methods.

What you *can* do, though is either this:

```
public ActionResult Filter(string criteria1, string criteria2)
```

and then check whether `criteria2` is null to filter only by name.

Alternatively, you can use `ActionNameAttribute` to decorate your action methods

```
[ActionName("FilterByName")]
public ActionResult Filter(string criteria1)

[ActionName("FilterByNameAndRanking")]
public ActionResult Filter(string criteria1, string criteria2)
```

and then use that name in route registration. This approach, however, can lead to much confusion.

Comment: How different is this from having a separate action name
ie:
isnt the above same as having 2 different action methods like
public ActionResult FilterByName(string criteria1)

public ActionResult FilterByNameAndRanking(string criteria1, string criteria2)